# How can I make a multiple for loop with each value getting in one at a time?

Tags: python

```
T_list = []
Temp_k = np.linspace(298, 398, 10)
#print (Temp_k)
current = np.linspace(0, 1.4, 5)
ppH2O = np.linspace(-2, -1, 5)

H2_pressure = []
H2O_pp = ppH2O
for i in (Temp_k):
    print(i, 'i')
    for j in (H2O_pp):
        print(j, 'j')
        for k in (current):
            print (k, 'k')
            partial_H2 = 5*np.exp((1.653 * k)/i) - 1/j
H2_pressure.append(partial_H2)
#print (H2_pressure)
```

I want to make a list of an array that gives me the values of
5*np.exp((1.653 * k)/i) - 1/j,

At each Temp_k, H2O_pp, current.

For example, value of when Temp_k , H2O_pp and current is at their initial value,
value at their second value, .... till it reaches to the end values.

Could someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

What about this

```
import numpy as np

temp_k = np.linspace(298, 398, 10)
pp_h2o = np.linspace(-2, -1, 5)
currents = np.linspace(0, 1.4, 5)

h2_pressures = []
for temp in temp_k:
    for pp in pp_h2o:
        for current in currents:
            h2_pressure = 5 * np.exp((1.653 * current) / temp)  - 1 / pp
            h2_pressures.append(h2_pressure)
            print(f'temp: {temp:0.1f}, pp: {pp:.2f}, current: {current:.3f}, h2_pressure: {h2_pressure:.4f}')

#print(h2_pressures)
```

Changes:

- choose more logical variable names conform Python convention
- removed the () around the lists in the for loops
- put the h2_pressures.append in the inner for loop
- format the print out

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you put append outside of every loop. You should append what you calculated at the most inner loop, where you calculated it. Otherwise when loop is terminated there is no access to previously calculated values.

```
T_list = []
Temp_k = np.linspace(298, 398, 10)
#print (Temp_k)
current = np.linspace(0, 1.4, 5)
ppH2O = np.linspace(-2, -1, 5)

H2_pressure = []
H2O_pp = ppH2O
for i in (Temp_k):
    print(i, 'i')
    for j in (H2O_pp):
        print(j, 'j')
        for k in (current):
            print (k, 'k')
            partial_H2 = 5*np.exp((1.653 * k)/i) - 1/j
            H2_pressure.append(partial_H2)
```